# Simple ReactJS code not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following Simple ReactJS code is not working. Newbie needs help please!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ReactJS Test</title>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
var currentLocation = window.location;
ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
            <p>currentLocation : {currentLocation}</p>
        </div>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And Chrome console shows helpless error messages like this:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:67 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #31; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=http%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxx.com%3A8080%2F_test%2Fsitetest_new.jsp&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at m (react-dom.production.min.js:67)
    at qb (react-dom.production.min.js:82)
    at z (react-dom.production.min.js:87)
    at C (react-dom.production.min.js:89)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:94
    at g (react-dom.production.min.js:43)
    at f (react-dom.production.min.js:43)
    at beginWork (react-dom.production.min.js:48)
    at e (react-dom.production.min.js:18)
    at k (react-dom.production.min.js:19)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you visit the link provided or use a non-production build?

Comment: Yes, it shows "Objects are not valid as a React child"

Answer (score 3):

[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) returns an object. You can't embed a standalone object in JSX. You can only embed [JavaScript expressions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx).

Try using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert your object to a string.

You can run the snippet below or check out this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/aLWZvP)**.

```js
var currentLocation = window.location;

ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
            <p>currentLocation : {JSON.stringify(currentLocation)}</p>
        </div>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Note:** If you just want a string value from your `window.location` object (e.g. `href`), you don't need `JSON.stringify()`.

You could simply use `window.location.href` directly in your JSX (or set `var currentLocation = window.location.ref;`) - [example](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/YrVWYw).

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped :)